# Custom chat interface for Microsoft Chatbot

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I would like to build a custom chatbot application using Microsoft Bot framework based on the following image
[image: User Interface]

How does this work with images and buttons? Do we need to handle each button /card uniquely?
Do we need to take care of rendering in a mobile application as well? Any help or directions to available samples and strategy would be useful.

Comment: Was my answer adaquate? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably too broad of a question for Stack Overflow, so my answers will be broad, but I'll do what I can to answer this.

> I would like to build a custom chatbot application using Microsoft Bot framework based on the following image

You can use [WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) to accomplish this, although to get that kind of customization will take a lot of work. These might be good samples to look at:

- [05.b.idiosyncratic-manual-styling](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/05.b.idiosyncratic-manual-styling/)
- [21.customization-plain-ui](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/21.customization-plain-ui)

To get the form/card you have in the middle, use [Adaptive Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots)

> How does this work with images and buttons? Do we need to handle each button /card uniquely?

You have a lot of flexibility in designing Adaptive Cards. Here are [some samples](https://adaptivecards.io/samples/). [This blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) will tell you just about everything you need for how to implement them.

They work well with images and buttons and can be handled uniquely

> Do we need to take care of rendering in a mobile application as well?

Both WebChat and Adaptive Cards work well in a mobile environment. Consider them "responsive".